# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'var'

Tags: c#, string, cryptography, var

I am getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'var'

```
using System.Web.Helpers;

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        var ss = Crypto.HashPassword("1234");

        Response.Write(ss);
    }
}
```

Comment: try replace `ss` type to `System.String` - what happens?

Comment: now it is working. It converts to hash password. So I just need to ask, If I take ss as string, it is ok? OR var would give the different result.

Comment: I believe it won't make a difference, especially if you only writes it back with `Response.Write`

Comment: but If i want to save it as a password in database instead of Responce.Write()

Comment: So, you have to give the full description of your problem in order to get a complete answer... :) - write a new question and provide all details

Comment: Do you have a class called `var`? That's the only cause for this weird error I can think of. Right click on `var` and choose "Goto definition".

Comment: One thing to mention: a good practice is to use "var" when you can deduce what the var replaces by looking at the right side of the =.
HashPassword is not the case, does it return a string? a byte array?

Comment: Great, you broke the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare `ss` as `System.String`.

According to `Crypto.HashPassword` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.hashpassword(v=vs.111).aspx), the return value is of type `System.String`